# Trying to understand a snippet

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to understand the following IF statement and what `res` does.

```
   if sentence is not None:
                # gps successfully parsed a message from module
                # see if we have valid coordinates
                res = check_for_valid_coordinates(gps)
```

Given below is the full code. Does it just run the function?

```
GPS_TIMEOUT_SECS=10
# init I2C to P21/P22
i2c = machine.I2C(0, mode=I2C.MASTER, pins=('P22', 'P21'))
# write to address of GPS
GPS_I2CADDR = const(0x10)
raw = bytearray(1)
i2c.writeto(GPS_I2CADDR, raw)
# create MicropyGPS instance
gps = MicropyGPS()
# store results here.
last_data = {}
print("Start reading GPS data...")
def check_for_valid_coordinates(gps):
    if gps.satellite_data_updated() and gps.valid:
        last_data['date'] = gps.date_string("long")
        last_data['latitude'] = gps.latitude_string()
        last_data['longitude'] = gps.longitude_string()
while True:
    # read some data from module via I2C
    raw = i2c.readfrom(GPS_I2CADDR, 16)
    # feed into gps object
    for b in raw:
        sentence = gps.update(chr(b))
        if sentence is not None:
            # gps successfully parsed a message from module
            # see if we have valid coordinates
            res = check_for_valid_coordinates(gps)
print("Finished.")
if 'date' in last_data:
    print("@ ", last_data['date'])
if 'latitude' in last_data and 'longitude' in last_data:
    print("> ", last_data['latitude'], " ", last_data['longitude'])
i2c.deinit()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Python functions return None by default. check_for_valid_coordinates(gps) is called and None is assigned to res afterwards.

Comment: `gps.update(chr(b))` is a function call - lookup it's API documentation for its details on behaviour. It can return `None` which in Python is like `null`/`nil` in other languages. 

If the returned value is `None`, the if statement is ignored, and the next raw value is parsed. If it is `None`, then it'll execute that block.